# Check which com port my device uses?

Tags: windows-vista, serial-port, com

I have a device hooked up to the USB connector and within it's software i have to choose which com port it uses. With Windows XP i would go to the device manager and go to com devices/ports where it is listed. This regularly changed somehow so most of the time i had to look it up.

Now i need this device to work on a vista machine but i cannot find any information about the com ports that give me the information i need. It goes from COM1 to COM21 so it is hard to locate it manualy by trial and error.

-edit-
I even got COM 24 today when hooking up the device to my XP laptop through USB.

Comment: Does a USB port use a COM port?  I didn't think it did.  A COM port is used by Serial ports.

Comment: Yeah, didn't know it either before i started using this device. It is a Keller log device that measures presure. I have to download the data from these devices. I hook them up with a USB cable. My digifobian coleagues say it won't work on vista but i'm not sure, just need to find that com port list inside vista.

Comment: Are they not listed in Device Manager?  Right-click My Computer, and choose Manage, then you can see Device Manager.

Comment: @steve No, I believe that option is not available in vista. I'm looking for a workaround. A dos command or perhaps a program. However i tried all the listed com ports in the program with the device hooked up, none of them worked.

Comment: Why does this get downvoted? Explain please...